# problem regarding product of cycles of a permutation.

Tags: group-theory

[image]
Its a rather easy question . I tried breaking up into transpositions but my answer doesn't match any of these options anyone please explain in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate the image of each number under the permutation would be easier.

$1\rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 2$
$2\rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 3$
$3\rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 5$
$5\rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 6$
$6\rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 4$
$4\rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 1$

So the answer would be $(123564)$, d

Also, you should state that the composition of permutations in your problem is from left to right.